# slightly more complicated many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, join, many-to-many

I have a single table that has 2 many-to-many relationships to another table.  E.g.:

```
main
====
id
leftOptions
rightOptions

options
=======
id
option
```

I need to connect both leftOptions and rightOptions to the options table, so I can't make the usual junction table, with mainId and optionsId as keys.

Also, I'm using mysql, so I'd need something that works with that software.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways:

```
main        mainToOptions        options
====        ============         =======
id          mainId               id
            optionId             option
            isLeft
```

Or

```
main        mainToLeftOptions       mainToRightOptions       options
====        =================       ==================       =======
id          mainId                  mainId                   id
            optionId                optionId                 option
```

However, it's really hard to say which one you should choose without a bigger picture,

Comment: Thank you!  I'm going to give the 2nd one a shot.